# trace logs level for error logs and minimum log level

Tags: 2013, uls, monitoring

i want to configure trace logs for below service applicatons and logging level which one is suitable options?

The services have the following logging requirements: - Business Connectivity Services must have only the minimum logging level. - Word Automation Services must log all errors. - The Search service logs must log all activity. You need to apply the appropriate trace log diagnostic level for each service.
The services have the following logging requirements:

- Business Connectivity Services must have only the minimum logging level.
- Word Automation Services must log all errors.
- The Search service logs must log all activity.

which appropriate trace log from below  should apply for each service.

Unexpected

HIgh

medium

verbose
Is high logging level is log all errors?

Answer (score 1):

BCS you would set to 'Unexpected'; WAS you would set to 'Verbose' (or VerboseEx if done via `Set-SPLogLevel`) as you would with Search.

I do not recommend using Verbose/VerboseEx in production for long periods of time as they can cause a decrease in farm performance.

Comment: hi unexpected and high logging levels show errors in uls logs ?

Comment: Unexpected are 'errors'. High isn't necessarily an error.